# AS3 AIR package set "included files" with relative paths

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-cs5

In Flash professional under Publish>AIR Settings>General there is an option "Included files" where one can add files or folders to be included in that AIR packaged file.

If the file is in the root folder of the opened .fla file it adds the file with a relative path but if the file is outside that .fla directory it adds the files with an absolute path.

Now my question is: Is there a way to set the files or folders to be added for packaging using a relative path?
say for example ../assets/images ?
or is there an AIR properties file that can be edited?

Im doing an App for android, iOS and desktop and with relative paths it would make it much easier to manage the assets.

I've been searching for an answer to this question but have not found one, so I'd appreciate the help thanks,
Bob.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to automatically do this. You could package all assets within different directories and load only the platform specific ones at runtime.

If you determine which platform the app is running on with something like:

```
import flash.system.Capabilities;
private var platformVariable:String;

if (Capabilities.manufacturer.indexOf("iOS") != -1) {
platformVariable = "iOS";
} else if (Capabilities.manufacturer.indexOf("Android") != -1) {
platformVariable = "android";
} else {
platformVariable = "desktop";
}
```

Then have 3 directories within your local includes directory:
includes > iOS
includes > android
includes > desktop

Then use the platformVariable variable to construct a path to the relevant directory

```
_urlRq = new URLRequest("includes/"+platformVariable+"itemToBeLoaded"); 
_urlRq.method  = URLRequestMethod.GET;          
_urlLoader = new URLLoader();
```